# Read UI Label Value and Perform some tasks

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm creating a radio application with 5 radio stations. I've included [Rotary Wheel](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9864/how-to-create-a-rotating-wheel-control-with-uikit) to select the preferred station. I then use a label view to display the selected station. When the user presses the play button how can I get the selected value to play a defined URL.

I've defined 5 URL's already, but I am not sure how to get the play button to play the the selected station at the URL when user presses play.

Comment: you need to look up AVAudioPlayer in the objc framework. You will also need to look up how to play url locations depending on if you need wifi/internet access to play these urls(s)

Comment: Hi thanks .. i know how to play 1 url , but i want to know how to play user selected url when press play button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if  you are looking to play multiple urls, you create a method that plays them by a certain switch-case statement.. such as the following

```
- (void) playMusicAtIndex:(int)index {
  switch(index) {

     case 0:
       // play url 1;
       break;

     case 1:
      // play url 2;
      break;

     case 2:
        // play url 3;
        break;
     …
    }
}
```

then, when you are going off the selected option for the url of the radio, just set the url at a certain index number, and then do (inside the method)

```
[variableName playMusicAtIndex:0..or 1.. or 2, whatever index you're playing];
```

hope this helps!